# PageFactory clear cache on driver.quit();

Tags: selenium-webdriver, factory-pattern, pageobjects

I have been using `PageFactory` from long time. I also use `@CacheLookup` to cache the WebElements. Problem is I never noticed any speedy execution of tests. It looks same all the time.

1. How do I verify that when it is caching and when it is not?
2. How do I clear cache, does `driver.quit();` do the job?

Answer (score 0):

Generally, when you use a `@FindBy` annotation, all it does lazily is calls a `findElement` on the DOM. So something like this:

```
`findElement(By.cssSelector("div.v-button.v-button-action"));`
```

This search is being performed each time you are using this element. When you annotate the element with `@CacheLookup`, the same search result is being reused, without doing an additional search.

I am not sure how to effectively test the performance of this feature as in some cases it might not produce a greatly different results. I guess that the difference might be a bit more evident when searching by xpath rather than by css for example as xpath is usually slower. Perhaps you can try that and see how that looks.

I reckon that `driver.quit()` will do the job as it internally stops the webdriver instance and ends the session.